# How many final digits have in common these two numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider these two numbers:

$2^{541455}-1$ and $2^{51455}-1$.

Is there a way to calculate the Number of final digits that these two numbers have in common?

My idea Is to use

$2^{541456}-1\equiv 2^{51456}-1\pmod {10^k}$
Because for k>5

$2^{541455}\neq 2^{51455}\pmod {10^k}$, I conclude that the two numbers share in common the last 5 digits.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! [It is advisable that you take a tour to see what we are about](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/#27933)").

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: It is enough to take the difference and to determine the 2-adic and 5-adic valuation of this difference. The minimum of those (here the $5$-adic valuation because the $2$-adic valuation is huge) is the desired result.

Comment: In other words , the largest $k$ such that $5^k$ divides the difference.